# Slide button text

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, ejs

Could someone tell me why isn't my text "Add Product" appearing inside of the button when the user hovers on the button?
Adding

> display: flex

for the body seems to fix the issue but I don't wanna set the display of my body to flex. Is there some other way I could make it work?

```css
.button {
  background: #f6bc00 no-repeat -12px center;
  border: 1px solid #f6bc00;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: 700;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px 8px 3px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: padding .2s ease, background-position .2s ease, transform .5s ease;;
}

.button:span {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.button:hover {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  padding-left: 88px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  background-position: 5px center;
}

.button span:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  left: -70px;
  transition: left .2s ease;
}

.button:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 20px;
}

/* PRESENTATION */
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.button:nth-child(1) {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#" download="">
  <span>Add Product</span>
  <span>Add</span></a>
```

Comment: because you have .button span:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;

Comment: I see, any idea how I could fix it?

Comment: remove position: absolute;

Comment: I want "Add Product" to appear when the user hovers on the button.

Comment: like this, https://jsfiddle.net/hp5d6wqk/? sorry I am not sure what you want

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is to hide the add product text.

i changed this..

```
.button span:nth-child(1) {
 position: absolute;
 left: -70px;
 transition: left .2s ease;
 }
```

to this..

```
.button span:nth-child(1) {
display:none;
transition: left .2s ease;
}
```

then on hover display inline

```
.button:hover span:nth-child(1) {
 display:inline;
 bottom: 3px;
 }
```

checkout the codepen.
https://codepen.io/cartoonzzy/pen/PoGYowZ